# Excel formula deletion using php Laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, phpexcel, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I want to modify an already existing excel sheet with delete the formula without affecting the values in the cell which are generated by those formula used in the sheets using PHP.
I tried to use php Spreadsheet. Not able to delete the formula used the excel sheets
Is there some way I can modify the already existing excel sheet with removing the formula using PHP?

Comment: Hi, not sure what people are using these days but you'll want to find that lib and use it.  Question will get closed but hopefully you can get some suggestions or goolge it yourself. My fingers suggest: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet aswell so maybe you can share some code?